# Django Allauth dynamic LOGIN_URL

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth on my website to handle user login/logout/signup.

For now I simply want users to be able to login/register from every page on the site.

For this purpose i added a bootstrap modal to my base.html, accessible over a button in the header.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form method='post' action='/accounts/login/?next={{ request.get_full_path }}' id='login'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ login_form|crispy }}
        <input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" value='Log In'>
    </form>
</div>
```

I used a context processor to provide the LoginForm from allauth:

```
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm

def login_form(request):
    return {
        'login_form': LoginForm
    }
```

This works well as long as the login data is correct. I get redirected to my source page with a logged in state.

Now if a user enters a wrong password, the allauth template in /accounts/login gets rendered and the error messages displayed. I would like to override the LoginForm/LoginView in a way that it calls the view from the request and adds the form (with errors) to the context.

Is this possible?

**Update:** 
I found that I probably need to overwrite form_invalid in the LoginView and set it to the view i came from adding the form to the context_processor?

Comment: Maybe you can check the username and password via AJAX and then submit if successful.